# adding your own xml comments to the returned properties and methods of a soap response

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, soap, web

My application is using a public web service and the properties, objects and fields that I access in the response don't have any comment documentation in the visual studio IDE, (either the developers of the web service didn't think it would be useful or just couldn't be bothered.)

Is there any way I could add my own xml style comments for all these, after the fact, so to speak.

I'm thinking, xml serializer class could perhaps be used and I loop through nodes of the entire response, somehow adding my own c# comments to each property and member as I go ??

```
/// <summary>
/// The web response members don't have any useful comments here - which I would like !!!
/// </summary>
/// <param name = ... etc
someType aReturnedProperty
{
  get { return aRetProp; }
  set { aRetProp = value; }
}
```

Comment: Figured it! So simple!  Just add the <summary> tags to the code inside the proxy class as you would normally to any class member. (that's the auto-generated one that inherits SoapHttpClientProtocol and that VS tells you you should'nt modify! :)

Comment: Do you want that when you generate your proxy class, it include the comment documentation from the web serevices?

Comment: There was no comment documentation returned by the web service - that's my point!!